# PHP: Parse string ["key", "value"] into associative array

Tags: php, arrays, string, parsing

How can I parse a string of the following format into an associative array?

```
[ ["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"], ["key3", "value3] ]
```

Into:

```
Array
(
    ["key1"] => "value1"
    ["key2"] => "value2"
    ["key3"] => "value3"
)
```

Thanks!

edit: The data is in a string format i.e:

```
$stringdata ='[ ["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"], ["key3", "value3"] ]';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop and loop through the whole array and assign your values into a new array using the first element as key and the second element as value. Usually like this:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $arr) {
    $new_array[$arr[0]] = $arr[1];
}
```

But to parse the string into an array I would take the following RegEx approach and then a loop:

```
$str = '[ ["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"], ["key3", "value3"] ]';
preg_match_all('/(\[("(.*?)"), ("(.*?)")\])/i', $str, $matches);
//Now we have in $matches[3] and $matches[5] the keys and the values
//and we would now turn this into an array using a loop

$new_array = array();
for($k = 0; $k < count($matches[3]); $k++) {
    $new_array[$matches[3][$k]] = $matches[5][$k];
}
```

See this live demo https://3v4l.org/u3jpl

Answer (score 0):

Use functional approach with [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

```
<?php
$ar = [ ["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"], ["key3", "value3"] ];
$newAr = array_reduce($ar, function($carry, $item) {
    $carry[$item[0]] = $item[1];
    return $carry;
});

var_dump($newAr);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["key1"]=>
  string(6) "value1"
  ["key2"]=>
  string(6) "value2"
  ["key3"]=>
  string(6) "value3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
<?php

$json = json_decode('[["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"], ["key3", "value3"]]');

$final = array();
foreach($json as $value) {  
    $final[] = array($value[0]=>$value[1]);
}
```

`final` is the array in your required format.